# Continuously build Vue lib

Tags: vue.js, build, vue-cli, monorepo, lerna

So I have a monorepo that has some Vue apps inside of it, and one package that exports Vue components.

When I want to start the app, I need to build the package that the app is dependent on.
Command is: `vue-cli-service build --target lib src/index.ts`

When I work on the app & package simultaneously, it is really annoying to have to run the build after each change to the package.
Is there a way to have it as hot/live build which when there are changes it will trigger a build for the package?

Comment: is that a TypeScript build? I have a monorepo project and use `lerna run --parallel` and use `tsc --incremental --watch` and it's auto-watching and rebuilding fine, the only problem I have is the editor doesn't detect TS interface change but that's a small editor thing which I found a small trick to deal with that. On the other hand, another alternative can be to use something like pnpm workspace and Vite lib watch mode which also works really great, I created a project with that [vue3-pnpm-workspace](https://github.com/ghiscoding/vue3-pnpm-workspace)

Comment: @ghiscoding
Hmmmm, I'm not sure how vue-cli builds behind the stage, I'll check wether I can just use tsc